# send data from android to PC via USB

Tags: android, usb

How to send a simple data (with java programming) from android to PC connected via USB? I am using android 2.3.3. Also can someone tell me what APIs should i look for doing this? ..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See the android USB-Host documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/host.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But doesn't connecting android to PC come under USB-Accessory mode??

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like this: `http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/005777a9193abf24#`

Comment: @Dyonisos Link doesn't work.